# Grid and pseudo selectors not working correctly with material-ui

Tags: css, grid, material-ui

I have the following style working with pure CSS but with material-ui the pseudo selectors are not working.

```
five: {
    display: 'grid',
    position: 'relative',
    gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3, 2fr)',
    '&:nth-child(4)': {
        gridColumn: '1/3',
        gridRow: '2'
    },
    '&:nth-child(5)': {
        gridColumn: '2/6',
        gridRow: '2'
    }
}
```

The target is to have the following layout where 'O' is just empty space and X are the elements:

X O X O X

O X O X O

Can this be done without pseudo selectors or is there perhaps a mistake in the current code that i'm missing?

Comment: The pseudo-selectors work fine for me here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nth-child-selectors-yrhqw. Please provide a code sandbox that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Please show the code that uses these styles.